# Redux-form field array, adding a selector for each new item in the array

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a Redux-form that contains a field-array. Is there a way to build a selector for each item in the field array? For context I'm just doing this so I can total them in a separate field.

```
const selector = formValueSelector('mainForm');

export const mapState = (state, ownProps) => {
    const test1 = selector(state, 'test.0.total'); 
    const test2 = selector(state, 'test.1.total');
  return {
    test1,
    test2
  };
};
```

Is there a was to loop through each item in `test` and return its `.total` added together? I'm struggling to come up with syntax for this... I'm thinking something like the following, but how do I make dynamic with respect to the total number of items in the array (the way the selectors work in redux-form confuses me a bit, is there a way to use Reselect maybe)?

```
const selector = formValueSelector('mainForm');

export const mapState = (state, ownProps) => {
    const test1 = selector(state, 'test.0.total'); 
    const test2 = selector(state, 'test.1.total');
    const sum = test + test1;
  return {
    test1,
    test2,
    sum
  };
};
```